# DataFrame to sql statement?

Tags: python, oracle, pandas, dataframe, cx-oracle

I have a dataframe that I want to be able to convert into a sql query i.e.
each column of dataframe are various select things which is union with each column.

In R, for mtcars we get something like:

```
"select 'Mazda RX4' ROWNAME,21 MPG,6 CYL,160 DISP,110 HP,3.9 DRAT,2.62 WT,16.46 QSEC,0 VS,1 AM,4 GEAR,4 CARB from dual union all select 'Mazda RX4 Wag' ROWNAME,21 MPG,6 CYL,160 DISP,110 HP,3.9 DRAT,2.875 WT,17.02 QSEC,0 VS,1 AM,4 GEAR,4 CARB from dual union all......"
```

I saw some help with create and insert statement but is there an easy way to do it for select statements as well??